# Drawing my view on top of navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I draw my custom view on top of navigation bar? I am trying to get a control like Google chrome's more button.

[image]

Comment: Of course this can be done, you've already answered that with an example. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have taken kxMenu classes from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kxmenu. But the view drawn with kxMenu goes below navigation bar button.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using kxmenu for drawing the view.
Instead of drawing the menu in self.view, draw it in screen window.That way, you could draw over the navigation bar.

Further, to exactly replicate the Google's popup action. Follow these steps 
1. Create a tableview, populate with options, Give a header view with the share, reload, and favourite menus

2. Find the touch point on the screen, i.e, in your case, the centre of the right bar button
3. Add the table to

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow
4. Animate the table